# Replace NULLs with value

Tags: sql-server, insert, null, replace, isnull

Here is my temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #test123(
    c1 float,
    c2 float,
    c3 float,
    c4 float,
    c5 float
);

INSERT #test123(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
VALUES (2,3,NULL,1,2),
       (2,NULL,NULL,1,2),
       (2,3,NULL,NULL,2),
       (NULL,3,NULL,1,NULL),
       (2,3,NULL,1,2);
```

When I run the following querys to replace all NULLs in the first column

```
INSERT INTO #test123 (c1) VALUES (ISNULL(c1,0));
```

or

```
INSERT INTO #test123 (c1) SELECT CASE WHEN c1 IS NULL THEN 0  END AS c1;
```

I receive both time the error "Invalid column name 'c1'."

The Syntax  ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)) of `INSERT INTO` is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to **update** values, you need to use **`UPDATE`**, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE #test123 
SET c1 = 0
WHERE c1 IS NULL ;
```